# Passing on the download progress to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, progress-bar, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking and I can successfully download a file from a web server.

Now I can also see the progress bar fill up by using the following code and method:

```
_operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:_streamingURL append:NO];

[_operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
```

My question is now:

**Am I able to see the progress on another ViewController? which would then be my downloading ViewController???**

I can pass through the title to the cell and the tableView only appears when the array has got content to give. I just need to show the progress:-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have already solved this by now, but for others reading this:

I would suggest that you create a singleton class that acts as your "API Client". From there you do your download request and when you push to a new UIViewController you simply ask the API Client for the current download progress.

That way you don't have to mess with notifications or passing a bunch of values around between ViewControllers.